# How to compile C# class library project with mono (linux)?

Tags: c#, dll, mono, msys2, gmcs

Using [C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe), in Windows I can successfully create a `.dll` file from a `C# project`, using the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/my/directory/with/.csproj/file
csc /target:library /out:NameOfNewDll.dll /recurse:*.cs
```

But, I need to do the same with the `MSYS2` Linux environment, where I already have access to [mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) and `msc` and `csc` commands. My project is actually a class library project, with many classes (so it's not classical application with an entry point).

What I am trying to do is:

```
mcs /path/to/my/directory/with/.csproj/file/*.cs /target:library /out:NameOfNewDll.dll /recurse:*.cs
```

But it's not working. I can not compile class by class since they all have references one to another and I need one general `.dll` file that will represent my whole class library project.
I read somewhere about xbuild, but as I understood this is now deprecated tool.

Comment: If you have .NET Core CLI(SDK) package, you can build a csproj in Linux systems. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Comment: _"Linux environment...My project is actually a class library ... (so it's not classical application with an entry point)."_ - Strangely enough, Windows developers are also known to create class libraries ;)